# Why does SCID call itself "Structured" when by many accounts it's semi-structured?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, terminology, test, history-of-psychology, dsm

The "S" in SCID officially stands for "Structured" as in Structured Clinical Interview for DSM. But as far as I can tell for the last three editions (5, IV and III), non-official sources (research papers etc.) often refer to it as a 
[semi-structured interview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-structured_interview). e.g. [[0]](https://www.appi.org/products/structured-clinical-interview-for-dsm-5-scid-5), [[1]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Deborah_Glasofer/publication/302432474_Structured_Clinical_Interview_for_DSM-IV_SCID/links/58fa1fca4585152edeceb1d0/Structured-Clinical-Interview-for-DSM-IV-SCID.pdf), [[2]](https://www.columbiapsychiatry.org/research/research-areas/services-policy-and-law/structured-clinical-interview-dsm-disorders-scid-0) / [[3]](https://www.columbiapsychiatry.org/research/research-areas/services-policy-and-law/structured-clinical-interview-dsm-disorders-scid-2), or [[4]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1637252) etc. The first link [0] is actually APA's own publishing blurb for SCID-5. The last one [4] is Spitzer et al. (1992) paper on SCID for DSM-III... which has over 4,000 citations in Google Scholar.

So why is there this discrepancy between the name (as fully spelled out) and content of the SCID?

---

I find it even more baffling after reading the introductory section of Spitzer et al., which emphasizes that SCID was designed from the get-go as semi-structured in opposition to previous [completely] structured interviews that were being advanced by others.

> The major contribution of DSM-III was its inclusion of
>   specified diagnostic criteria for virtually all of the mental
>   disorders. This made possible, at about the same time as
>   the publication of DSM-III, the development of the National Institute of Mental Health (NIMH) Diagnostic Interview Schedule (DIS). The DIS was designed for use by lay
>   interviewers with 1 week of intensive training. Although
>   originally developed for use in the Epidemiologie Catchment Area Study in which the cost of employing clinically
>   trained interviewers would have been prohibitive, it has
>   been used by investigators in a large number of nonepidemiologic
>   studies.
>   In the presidential address at the 1983 annual meeting of
>   the American Psychopathological Association, titled "Are
>   Clinicians Still Necessary?" one of us (R.L.S.) discussed the
>   potential limitations of the DIS in clinical research. Without questioning the advances embodied in the DIS, it was
>   argued that the most valid diagnostic assessment still required the skills of a clinician with experience in evaluating a range of psychopathology.
>
> Unlike a lay interviewer
>   administering a completely structured interview, such as
>   the DIS, an experienced clinician can tailor an interview by
>   phrasing questions to fit the subject's understanding, asking additional questions that clarify differential diagnosis,
>   challenging inconsistencies in the subject's account, and
>   judging whether the subject's description of an experience
>   conforms to the intent of a diagnostic criterion. This is
>   particularly true in the diagnostic evaluation of subjects
>   with psychotic symptoms who have little insight and
>   present with a complicated story from which the interviewer must discern the symptom profile. For these
>   reasons, two of us (R.L.S. and J.B.W.W.) started work on a
>   clinical assessment procedure that would not only be
>   linked to DSM-III but would incorporate several features
>   not present in previous clinical diagnostic instruments.

So was the naming of the SCID a case of ["embrace and extend"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) the concept of "structured" interview? I couldn't find the answer in Spitzer et al...